# Let a specific mob follow another mob

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was trying to make a horse follow exactly 3 blocks behind the horse that I am riding on.

I can do that by using teleport command and the new parameter `^^^`, but the result sucks as when I look up, the horse behind me will float, while it will sink into the ground when I look down.

I was thinking that maybe it has something to do with the new store command and motion of the horse.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: It's probably extremely hard to re-program a complete mob AI. How about just using llamas instead? They already do this, no commands needed.

Comment: Your using ^ for the y. This makes it float. I tried something similar with an armor stand, and it worked for a while, but I was tinkering with the commands and it broke. I made the armor stand.

Answer (score 0):

If you are riding the first horse then you should be able to put a lead on the second horse. The only downside is that you have to be constantly moving.
If you don't, then the second horse will go right behind you.

Hope this helps!